# non-refreshing div like facebook blue bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to make a non-refreshing menu like facebook with javascript or something?.
I want to put my radio player in a non-refreshing div or section. i've been looking but nothing. Only i got is load jquery function but that's not what i want. I want url changes.

Here there's a example website. It has a non-refreshing section on top and bottom. http://enladisco.com

Saludos and forgive my english.

Comment: Look into iframes or alternatively AJAX requests. For now however, I think this question is a little too broad to be answered within the scope of [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple method.

```
<header>
    My persistent header
</header>
<div>
    <iframe src="actualPageContent.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

When links are clicked, the browser does navigation inside the frame.  The downside is that the address bar doesn't change.

---

Use the script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688108/1074592) to dynamically load content into your main section, while leaving the header intact, and changing URLs in the browser.  The back button also works here.

Go with this if you can.

Answer (score 1):

That page is actually loading the content via ajax with $.ajax (which is what $.load will call) and not refreshing the page. check [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) to see how to modify the URL without triggering a refresh.